# Application_EndRequest triggered before request end?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have some simple classes that need to be disposed a the end of the request.

For that end I call the `Dispose` method on those objects from the `Application_EndRequest` event in `Global.asax`.

This "works fine on my machine" but causes some problems on my production server where I get `Cannot access a disposed object.` This happens in some MVC helpers.

It seemed to me like Application_EndRequest is triggered at the end of the request. Is this not the case? Is there another event I should be using to dispose my objects?

Comment: It seems to me like you're trying to dispose of something which has already been disposed. in this can can you not wrap the calls to .Dispose in a try {someObject.Dispose()} catch (ObjectDisposedException ex) {/*nothing to do*/} ?

Comment: the problem is the damn things are used, not disposed, after they have been disposed. I can wrap that in try/catch all I want, it would still make my site look bad.

Comment: Have you tried placing some logging/tracing in the Dispose method? You suggest that your problem occurs because App_EndRequest is triggered "before request end", but maybe something else is triggering the dispose?

Comment: as Jeroen said, you should check again if something else is not causing your objects to dispose. add a logger to trace whatever happens in ur code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Application pool issues - likely

I suspect that your disposable object isn't bound to request but rather app wide (it may be instantiated per request but it may be using some shared resources). As long as you're testing your application in development environment it seems to behave as expected but as soon as you put it in production you get issues. **This indicates you may have problems with application pool**.

IIS web application pool capabilities actually instantiate several `HttpApplication` instances for your application and they may all share common disposable resources. If that's the case with your disposable object and you're sharing it it may be that it isn't thread safe. The same would be true when you wouldn't wrap your shared resource usage inside thread safe operations.

That's why it may happen that while one request is in progress another one begins and the first one disposed the object while the second process still uses it.

#### More information is always helpful

If you'd explain the nature of your disposable object/resource and how you're using it in your application we could help you much better. But in the meantime, you could **[read my blog post](http://erraticdev.blogspot.co.uk/2011/01/how-to-correctly-use-ihttpmodule-to.html)** that talks about application pools and handling them. It's not about disposable objects per se, but you may still find all the information very useful and helpful.

Comment: It turns out I had actually declared the variables as static, even though they were never supposed to be. I never thought to check that.

Comment: I'm glad (200-times) my answer helped you resolve your issues. :) Sometimes we take certain things for granted not accounting for production environment particularities that actually make it possible for our apps to perform very well.

Comment: Actually it never occurred to me that to check the variables because I never thought that they should be static. I still don't know what exactly I was thinking when writing them.

Answer (score 2):

If you need some object disposable per-request to use inside your controllers, I would recommend you using controller's lifecycle handlers instead of using Application_BeginRequest and Application_EndRequest. See the following example.

The Controller:

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    protected override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);

        this.HttpContext.Items["MyDisposableObject"] = new MyDisposableObject();
    }

    protected override void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        base.OnResultExecuted(filterContext);

        if (this.HttpContext.Items.Contains("MyDisposableObject"))
        {
            var myDisposableObject = 
                    this.HttpContext.Items["MyDisposableObject"] as IDisposable;

            if (myDisposableObject != null)
            {
                myDisposableObject.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The `IDisposable` object:

```
public sealed class MyDisposableObject : IDisposable
{
    private bool disposed;

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (!this.disposed)
        {
            // Dispose all managed 
            // and unmanaged resources. 

            // Note disposing has been done.
            this.disposed = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I can have more than one controller per request, or I would have used this.

Comment: How do you have more than one controller per request in ASP.NET MVC 3?

Comment: @DmitryB. You can have multiple controllers and actions within one web requests. For instance if you use RenderAction in your views.

Answer (score 0):

If the objects are scoped to controller level you can override the `Dispose` method of `Controller` to dispose those objects.

```
protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
  if(disposing)
  {
    // dispose the objects here
  }

  base.Dispose(disposing);
}
```

If you are using some DI framework (like Ninject) in your application you can delegate that job to them.

Instead of disposing the objects at the end of the request you can also try wrapping them in an `using` statement wherever you access by this way you make sure the object is disposed.